# Python, Faker data is not generated

Tags: python, xlsxwriter, faker

i try to generate fake data using faker & write it to an excel sheet but data is not generated only header rows were written, let me know what i did wrong

```
import xlsxwriter
from faker import Faker

w_data = xlsxwriter.Workbook("new_data.xlsx")
s_data = w_data.add_worksheet()

s_data.write("A1","Name")
s_data.write("B1","Email")
s_data.write("C1","SSN")
s_data.write("D1","Phone Number")
s_data.write("E1","Address")

f_data = Faker()
name=[]
email=[]
ssn=[]
phone_number=[]
address=[]

def generate_data():
    
    name.append(f_data.name())
    email.append(f_data.email())
    ssn.append(f_data.ssn())
    phone_number.append(f_data.phone_number())
    address.append(f_data.address())
    return name,email,ssn,phone_number,address
    
    for row_num, data in range (0,1000):
        s_data.write(row_num+1,0,name)
        s_data.write(row_num+1,1,email)
        s_data.write(row_num+1,2,ssn)
        s_data.write(row_num+1,3,phone_number)
        s_data.write(row_num+1,4,address)

        
generate_data()
w_data.close()
```

Comment: You `return` before you write anything into the file. What did you expect to happen? `return` leaves the function, anything after it wont be executed. You also do nothing with the stuff that `generate_data()` returns ...

Comment: If you take out the `return` statement pointed out by @PatrickArtner, you'll have a problem with the next line.  `for row_num, data in range (0,1000):` is invalid Python.  Then, even if that worked, you'd be writing the same information to 1000 rows of the spreadsheet.  Is that what you want to do?  I would think that you'd want to call `Faker()` in the loop to produce different data, but of course, I'm just guessing that the `Faker` object will produce different data each time it is called.

Comment: Potential close voters: this isn't a typo, the whole logic of the program is flawed. It's a valid question for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you the results you want:

```
import xlsxwriter
from faker import Faker

w_data = xlsxwriter.Workbook("new_data.xlsx")
s_data = w_data.add_worksheet()

s_data.write("A1","Name")
s_data.write("B1","Email")
s_data.write("C1","SSN")
s_data.write("D1","Phone Number")
s_data.write("E1","Address")

f_data = Faker()

def generate_data(f_data):
    name = f_data.name()
    email = f_data.email()
    ssn = f_data.ssn()
    phone_number = f_data.phone_number()
    address = f_data.address()
    return name, email, ssn, phone_number, address
    
for i in range (0,1000):
    name, email, ssn, phone_number, address = generate_data(f_data)
    s_data.write(i, 0, name)
    s_data.write(i, 1, email)
    s_data.write(i, 2, ssn)
    s_data.write(i, 3, phone_number)
    s_data.write(i, 4, address)

        
w_data.close()
```

Instead of generating a list of 1000 entries for name, email, etc., then trying to write each entry one by one, we just refactor the function to generate one set of data at a time. In the `for` loop, we call the function and write the returned values, then go on to the next row. Since explicit is better than implicit, we pass the `f_data` Faker object to the function, so it doesn't have to rely on reading anything from the outside world.

Comment: I realize my code logic problem, Thanks for the guidance!